# cannot convert one type to another type error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a interface and a class which implements that interface as below:

```
public interface Grid_Result
{
}
public partial class Contract_GetSubsetList_Result : Grid_Result
{
}
```

I then have a method which I call to return an IEnumerable of Grid_Result items:

```
public IEnumerable<Grid_Result> GetModelForGrid(string fitlerBy, int filterType, int startIndex, int pageSize){...}
```

All this works fine, but when I try to call my method with:

```
List<Contract_GetSubsetList_Result> results = testcontroller.GetModelForGrid(regNumFilter, filterBy,
            startIndex, pageSize).ToList();
```

I get an error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Test.Grid_Result>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Test.Contract_GetSubsetList_Result>'
```

I'm not sure why, as Contract_GetSubsetList_Result does implement the Grid_Result interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant but `List<T>` is not, meaning you can't cast a `List<T>` to a `List<{superclass of T}>`

You can use `Cast<T>` to cast *before* the list is created:

```
List<Contract_GetSubsetList_Result> results = 
    testcontroller.GetModelForGrid(regNumFilter, filterBy, startIndex, pageSize)
                  .Cast<Contract_GetSubsetList_Result> // if you KNOW all objects will be of type Contract_GetSubsetList_Result
                  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

On this line

```
List<Contract_GetSubsetList_Result> results = testcontroller.GetModelForGrid(regNumFilter, filterBy, startIndex, pageSize).ToList();
```

all the compiler knows is that `GetModelForGrid` returns a list of `Grid_Result`. It doesn't know if those items are actually `Contract_GetSubsetList_Result` or not; you have to tell it explicitly with a cast:

```
List<Contract_GetSubsetList_Result> results = testcontroller.GetModelForGrid(regNumFilter, filterBy, startIndex, pageSize).Cast<Grid_Result>().ToList();
```