# Casting List of objects to a IList with the interface of the object

Tags: c#, .net, interface, casting, instance

I'm having a bit of a problem implementing an interface from a nuget package.
There is a property in the interface that looks like this: `IList<IInterfaceInstance> Implements {get;}`

My problem is casting from `List<InterfaceInstance>` to `IList<IInterfaceInstance>`.

This is what I'm trying to do and it gives me the following exception:

> Unhandled exception. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var ins1 = new InterfaceInstance() {Id = "1"};
        var ins2 = new InterfaceInstance() {Id = "2"};
        List<InterfaceInstance> imps = new List<InterfaceInstance>() {ins1, ins2};
        IList<IInterfaceInstance> implements = imps as IList<IInterfaceInstance>;

        foreach( var imp in implements) {
            Console.WriteLine(imp.Id);
        }
    }

    private class InterfaceInstance : IInterfaceInstance
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

    public interface IInterfaceInstance
    {
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: ILIst is not covariant so you cannot cast the generic type like that.  You could cast it to `IEnumerable<IItnerfaceInstance>` since you can only get items out of `IEnumerable`.  Otherwise you need to cast each item for this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#as-operator):

> The as operator explicitly converts the result of an expression to a
>   given reference or nullable value type. If the conversion is not
>   possible, the as operator returns null.

In general, generic types don't allow variance of its arguments, meaning you cannot cast to a different type. This is why `implements` is null and it fails when trying to perform the `foreach`.

To achieve your intention, you'll have to cast each independent item to `IInterfaceInstance`, not the whole list.

Answer (score 1):

You could use linq to select a new ienumerable, passing a lambda to cast each `InterfaceInstance` as `IInterfaceInstance`:

```
IList<IInterfaceInstance> implements = imps.Select(interfaceInstance => (IInterfaceInstance)interfaceInstance).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

`IList` is not [covariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25328314/cannot-convert-one-type-to-another-type-error), so you can't cast `List<class>` to `IList<interface>`, and your `as` operator returns `null`. use `IEnumerable<IInterfaceInstance>` instead if all you want to do is iterate over the items.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast directly to `IList` like that because it is not co-variant.  Otherwise you would be able to add something that implements `IInterfaceInstance` but isn't `InterfaceInstance` into a list that should only have `InterfaceInstance`.  Instead you'd have to cast each item like this.

```
IList<IInterfaceInstance> implements = imps
    .Cast<IInterfaceInstance>()
    .ToList() as IList<IInterfaceInstance>;
```

Alternatively you can cast to `IEnumerable<IInterfaceInstance>` because it is co-variant because it only allows you to pull items out.

```
IEnumerable<IInterfaceInstance> implements = imps as IEnumerable<IInterfaceInstance>;
```